# Limited access to Amazon S3 buckets

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

Is it possible to somehow limit the access to an Amazon S3 account. I don't really like the idea of distributing my secret access key to all of my applications, that want to access just a single bucket on my account. If someone gains access to one of the applications, I could loose all my data stored on S3.

One way I was thinking to do it would be creating a second S3 account and give it access to just one bucket of the main account, but it's not really a great solution.

Another nice thing for me would be to give the secondary account only write (but not modify/delete) and read access. That way I could upload backups or other files and be sure, that they won't get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=43070&#43070) will answer your question:

Scroll down and start reading at Michael Fisher's answer.

> DO NOT hardcode your key on the
>   client.  The right way to do this is
>   (via a secure channel) to deliver a
>   pre-built request with an encrypted
>   signature -- this signature can be
>   built with the API provided by S3.
>
> You can extract the composition of the
>   encrypted signature reqest from one of
>   the request objects in the S3.cs class
>   (I am referring to the C#
>   implementation - not sure which you
>   are using but they should be pretty
>   analagous).  Then have your client
>   securely request the object from your
>   server side, and rather than spit back
>   the object, spit back the formated
>   request.  I believe this is the most
>   secure technique, assuming again that
>   you've properly secured the channel
>   (SSL, or whatever scheme you choose).